# Compiler and IIS dont trust relationship between domain and workstation

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to run a web application that worked fine on my XP machine but now it is on Windows 7.

When I run from compiler I get:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.SystemException: The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.


Source Error: 


Line 34:                     string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
Line 35: 
Line 36:                     bool yesno = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Group0Users");
Line 37: 
Line 38:                     string role = GetRole.OfUser(username);

Source File: C:\Users\agordon\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\Global.asax.cs    Line: 36 

Stack Trace: 


[SystemException: The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
]
   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Boolean& someFailed) +1185
   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean& someFailed) +44
   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess) +47
   System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +101
   EnterData.Global.Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\agordon\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\Global.asax.cs:36
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5420
```

And when I publish it on IIS and run it from there I get this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.SystemException: The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.


Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SystemException: The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
]
   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Boolean& someFailed) +1085
   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess) +46
   System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +128
   EnterData.Global.Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\agordon\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\Global.asax.cs:38
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5420
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: you try to access security information (ActiveDirectory/Domain or similar)... for this you need to authenticate with an account that has the appropriate permissions to do these things... the error just says that neither your machine nor your user has these permissions... BTW: any reason you don't use try/catch in your code ?

Comment: For some reason, I can't, but you should also tag this with "windows-7". I think the OS upgrade is a key to the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the machine password using:

```
NETDOM RESETPWD /Server:DC.Domain.tld /UserD:Administrator /PasswordD:xxx
```

Otherwise leave the domain and rejoin it using the GUI .